# Unable to upgrade my make version

Tags: 18.04, make, segmentation-fault

I tried this

```
cd /tmp
wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/make/make-4.1.tar.gz
tar xvf make-4.1.tar.gz
cd make-4.1/
./configure
make
sudo make install
cd ..
rm -rf make-4.1.tar.gz make-4.1
```

but on the `make` and `sudo make install` step I get the following

> segmentation fault  make
> segmentation fault  sudo make install

respectively.
No more no less. I'm completely baffled and clueless on what to do next

I'm running ubuntu 18.04

EDIT
This is what I get when I run `type -a make` and `apt policy make`
(Shell prompt is from oh-myzsh)

```
➜  ~ type -a make   
make is /usr/local/bin/make
make is /usr/bin/make
➜  ~ apt policy make
make:
  Installed: 4.1-9.1ubuntu1
  Candidate: 4.1-9.1ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 4.1-9.1ubuntu1 500
        500 https://zim.client-eng.a2z.com/ubuntu/prod bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
➜  ~
```

Comment: `make` is already at version 4.1 in the Bionic main repository - why are you trying to build it from source?

Comment: for some reason my make version is 3.8. And I realized I am not able to make anything. Running make always results in a segfault

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the outputs of `type -a make` and `apt policy make`

Comment: I've edited my question

Comment: wow thank you! I actually figured it out from here, i have no idea how the erroneous version of make got into /usrlocal/bin! your comments were a lifesave, I replcaed it after backing it up and everything works again!!